# Access "_t" element value from LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there a way to access the value of the "_t" element in a document when querying with LINQ from `MongoCollection.AsQueryable()`?

I have tried this:

```
_collection.AsQueryable()
           .Where(t => t.ToBsonDocument()
                        .GetValue("_t") == "someValue");
```

but I get the exception:

> Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression:
>   BsonExtensionMethods.ToBsonDocument(t).GetValue("_t").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't access the value in `_t` directly. You can however use `LINQ` to query the value using `GetType` or `is`:

```
_collection.AsQueryable().Where(doc => doc is Hamster);
_collection.AsQueryable().Where(doc => doc.GetType() == typeof(Squirrel));
```

This will generate the following queries:

```
{
    _t : "Hamster" 
}

{
    _t : "Squirrel"
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I tried that already but it doesn't seem to work. See my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187477/ambiguous-discriminator-mytype

Comment: @mclaassen It does work. Just maybe not when you create new types dynamically at run time

Comment: This does work under "normal" circumstances, just not for my dynamically created types.